Spectre.Console. Single choice group within multiple choice selection
I am new to Spectre.Console. I am trying to use a simple menu for a console utility.
var choiceConfig =
    new MultiSelectionPrompt<string>()
    .Title("Choose currencies to process")
    .PageSize(10)
    .InstructionsText(
        "[grey](Press [blue]<space>[/] to toggle a currency, " +
        "[green]<enter>[/] to accept)[/]")
    .choiceConfig.AddChoiceGroup("EUR", ["EUR", "EUR2"])
    .AddChoices(new[] {
         "GBP", "USD", "CAD"
    });

currencies = AnsiConsole.Prompt(choiceConfig).ToArray();


I would like the options under "EUR" to be single choice, so if I Select "EUR" "EUR2" unticks and the other way around.
Is this easy to do?
Thanks.

So, the "inner" choices shall be mutually exclusive? What do you expect to happen if the "outer" parent choice is selected?

I don't think there is (at least I don't see) a way in the current version to do this.
